# c# Create forms that have webBrowser in thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, webbrowser-control

I want to open small popup forms that have webBrowser control in thread(Not main thread) when it need to be alerted.

Just run the popup form in thread, got error

```
ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be 
instantiated
because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment.
```

So, I set the thread with STA mode, no error occurs. But, when there are more than one popup need to be run, they show up one by one. The second popup not appears until I close the first popup. And so on..
I want to show every popup at the same time in thread.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread th = new Thread(() =>
    {
        var arts = _Moniter.Mon();
        if (arts.Count < 1) return;

        foreach (var art in arts)
        {
            var f = new FormPopup(art, FormPopup.POPUP_MODE.NORMAL, Color.Yellow, 30000);
            Application.Run(f);
        }
    });
    th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);   // 
    th.IsBackground = true; // 
    th.Start();
}
```

Is there any way to show the forms that have webBrowser in no STA Thread?
Or How can I run multi forms at the same time with the STA Thread?

Comment: Why do you want to run it in a separate thread? why not just replace `Applicatio.Run(f);` in `f.Show();` to show multiple forms concurrent?

Comment: @PeterBons When I run with "f.Show();", all popup forms are closed immediately after show up. So, I used Application.Run(). I just want UI not stuck while Monitor working. because this job contains web parsing thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved problem myself by chance. Just have made and call popup form in the "Main form"'s Invoke(). There is no need to use STA Thread also. It could has other side effect by doing this. But, it looks working fine.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread th = new Thread(() =>
    {
        foreach (var art in arts)
        {
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>   // It works!
            {
                var f = new FormPopup(art, FormPopup.POPUP_MODE.NORMAL, Color.Yellow, 30000);
                f.Show();
            }));
        }
    });
    th.IsBackground = true; // 
    th.Start();
}
```